# Cron task late by few minutes

Tags: shell, cron, sh, cron-task

for some reason my `cron` job which is scheduled at `8 am` has been running late. Yesterday it ran at `8:01:14 am` and today at `8:02:29 am`. The job runs inside a container and is the only `cron` entry in the `crontab`. I read somewhere that if you have > 100 jobs `cron` will reschedule your job to run `60 seconds` later. But, since I am in a `container` on a `server` which has `2 container` with `1 job` per container I cant see how i would have over 100 `jobs` in the first place.

The `job` doesn't have any dependencies. Is there a way to see why this is happening? ever since I set this up 2 months ago it has been firing at `8:00 am` sharp, has only acted up last 2 days.

The task is just a basic `shell(.sh)` script

The time on `server` and `container` are both in sync (tested using `date` command). No changes have been made this week at all.

What is interesting is that the other process in the other container which is basically a duplicate of the first one ran on time.

Comment: Did you changed something yesterday? Did you test the scheduling of new `cron`entries (`date>/tmp/crontest.out`) ? Clock is still running on time or being synved to some other time (tomorrow job running at 8:03:43 am?). Is the cron started inside the container or is cron running on the host server and will the host server start the container?

Comment: @WalterA time on server and container are in sync. cron is in the container. I didnt change anything yesterday at all (not even the code).What is interesting is that the other process in the other container which is basically a duplicate of the first one ran on time.

Comment: How exactly do you know what time the job ran? Try a cron job that simply writes the output of the `date` command to a file.

Comment: @KeithThompson through my logs and output folders. the first thing the process does is that it creates a folder with the format $date$time.

Comment: @KeithThompson i added this line to my cron `* * * * * date >> /datetime.txt
` and when I `cat` the file i get `Wed Sep 20 17:01:01 EDT 2017` this seems to be running fine to me.

Comment: @pyjg: You described jobs running a minute or two late. Try running your `date` command every 10 minutes. As for the `$date$time` file, how do you determine that value? I'm suggesting that something other than late-running `cron` jobs might explain the problem, but you haven't given us complete information about what you're doing.

Comment: the $date$time is a folder created by the script. I think I know what is happening, for some reason in the morning it is taking longer to access the files on the network drive. I have this issue sometimes while using file explorer as well.

Comment: @KeithThompson for some reason, just now when i tried to access the network drive through file explorer, it took about 20 seconds to open a folder and was 'not responding' for a few seconds. Weird how it started happening just a couple days ago.